# Expand the rich:collapsiblePanel based on checkbox selection

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have 2 checkboxes and correspondingly 2 collapsible panels.
I want to achieve below mentioned validation:
If I check a checkbox only then I should be able to expand the corresponding collapsible panel.

Below is the that I tried but its giving me... update="HbR,Igl" Unhandled by MetaTagHandler for type org.ajax4jsf.component.behavior.AjaxBehavior  This error in the eclipse console.

```
                    </tr>
            </table>

 </rich:collapsiblePanel>

            <rich:collapsiblePanel id="Igl" style="height: 100%; resize:auto;"
                align="center" header="File Selection For Igloo"
                switchType="client" >
                <table id="nameTable1">
                    <tr>
                        <td><h:outputText value="Please Provide a name for the plot:" /></td>

                    </tr>
                </table>`enter code here`
                        </rich:collapsiblePanel>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </rich:panel>
```

Please advice on how to achieve this validation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `update` attribute for a4j:ajax, the proper attribute is `render`.

As to your question, you can collapse the panel by JavaScript:

```
RichFaces.$(panelId).switchPanel();
```

Or you can control the state by a server variable:

```
<rich:collapsiblePanel … expanded="#{bean.panelExpanded}">
```